# CivicRM 5.60 installation on WordPress 6.2 in Local 6.7.0 fails

Tags: wordpress, installation

I am trying to install CivicRM for WordPress site in Local environment https://localwp.com/. I unzip the CivicRM (5.60), I place the folder into app/public/wp-content/plugins/ folder. I see the plugin in WP admin interface. I click activate, install starts, but it fails shortly after and the whole WP site becomes unusable.

PHP: 8.0.22 MySQL: 8.0.16 WP: 6.2 webserver: nginx [![error in the wordpress backend][1]][1]

I tried to run the install a couple of times with different PHP, MySQL and webserver settings in Local, no change.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l92PJ.png

Comment: Welcome to SE!  What is in the CiviCRM log?  If you look in the database (using mysql / phpmyadmin etc) does the table exist?  Do other civicrm tables exist?

Comment: Hi, thanks! How do I access CivicRM log? I logged in the database through Adminer and I can see 12 tables, all starting with wp_.... Not sure how civicrm tables look like, but I would say none exists.

Comment: I have similar issue. Is there any resolution for this?
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Based on that screenshot - for whatever reason, the CiviCRM data wasn't loaded into the database.  Is it intentional that your MySQL database name for CiviCRM is `local`?

You can probably work around this by manually loading the contents of `civicrm_generated.mysql` (found in `<webroot>/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/sql`) into the database you specified as the CiviCRM database (which you can also double-check in `<webroot>/wp-content/uploads/civicrm.settings.php` in the `CIVICRM_DSN` constant).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not sure about MySQL database name - Local is the name of the environment in which I run whole WP server on my local machine so maybe that is why.

As for the workaround - I am able to find CIVICRM_DSN in civicrm.settings.php on the line starting with "define" - but I am not sure which file it references to.

  else {
    define('CIVICRM_DSN', 'mysql://root:root@localhost/local?new_link=true');
  }

Comment: @jjosseff That isn't a file - that's a MySQL connection string.  Compare it to the database connection info in `wp-config.php`.  The format is `<database software>://<user>:<password>@<server>/<database name>`.  So a) check that the user, password and server match wp-config.php. b) The database name can match WP or not - there are advantages to both - but if you didn't create a separate database manually using phpMyAdmin or similar, the database should be the same as WP. If WP is working, update the `CIVICRM_DSM` to match. `CIVICRM_UF_DSN` should *always* match `wp-config.php`.